# How to change a two-words phrase across a column in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like `my_df`. Across column `color`, I would like to change the content of all the cells that contain the word 'blue' into just the word 'blue' and end up with a dataframe like `my_df2`.

```
clothes <- c("skirt", "jacket", "shirt")
colors <- c("light blue", "dark blue", "ice blue")
my_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(clothes, colors))

color_blue <- c("blue", "blue", "blue")
my_df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(clothes, color_blue))
```

I have tried  this:

```
my_df[grepl("blue", my_df$colors),] == "blue"
```

Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subset your `my_df` using `grepl()`, which detects patterns and returns a logical vector.

```
clothes <- c("skirt", "jacket", "shirt", "shoes")
colors <- c("light blue", "dark blue", "ice blue", "grey")
my_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(clothes, colors))
my_df$color_blue[grepl("blue", my_df$colors)] <- "blue"
my_df
  clothes     colors color_blue
1   skirt light blue       blue
2  jacket  dark blue       blue
3   shirt   ice blue       blue
4   shoes       grey       <NA>
```